# How to capture responsebody from newman

Tags: newman

I want to capture the responsebody in Newman.

```
            const newman = require('newman'); 
            newman.run({
                collection: require('./xxx.json'),
                iterationData: './data.jsp',
                reporters: 'cli'
            }, function (err, summary) {
                if (err) { throw err; }
                console.log('collection run complete!');
                console.log(summary);
            });
```

I use the code above. it works fine but I want to capture the json output here from the call. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you used a wrong term for retrieving json response body. If you want to just get the response body you need to parse JSON returned and to save it to a variable.
If you would use newman to run through command line there are everything is super simple:

```
let body = JSON.parse(responseBody)
console.log(body)
```

and after test where you need to see the response you put this 2 lines of code.

But with your case perhaps you need that:
1) Callback option

```
const newman = require('newman'); 
            newman.run({
                collection: require('./xxx.json'),
                iterationData: './data.jsp',
                reporters: 'cli'
            }, function (err, summary) {
                if (err) { throw err; }
                console.log('collection run complete!');
                console.log(summary);
            })
.on('request', function (err, data) {
     // err, data can be used to write to files using the node fs module.
  });
```

or the better and modern option:

```
let response = await newman.run({
            collection: 'collection',
            environment: 'env',
        })
.on('request', async function (err, data) {
         // err, data can be used to write to files using the node fs module.
      });
        console.log(response)
```

Not sure I will be working as expected, but at least try.
Btw, where do you run these tests? just in clear env or use some runner framework.

Comment: I'll try your solutions tomorrow :). We run them as scripts in Jenkins now but will probably get some other destination to run.

Comment: Good luck! :-) Just to know, I run newman tests in TeamCity CI and for every request I have set parsing of reposne body and if 500 occurred or incorrect response value returned, console log works immediately and output the reason directly in Teamcity build log. I guess you wanna achieve the same. Any way, text back to know will it work or nah :-)

Comment: I tried the last solution but got: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function. I'm not a JS developer so my knowledge is very little. Will this solution only write output when there is an error or always? (I need always, I know the fs part isn't included yet of course)

Comment: I tried without the await etc and now I got output but stuff like this:      item: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     beforeScript: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ], with sometimes an ID of our app and appname

Comment: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function. Yeah, you need to add async to the function in which you run the code in order to use await. Try to parse the response where you get item: [ [Object], [Object] ], console.log(response) or variable where your response is written in: response.item[0] it should reach the [object] and will show us what inside

Comment: Den, Have you run the first option?

Comment: this isn't very clear answer, there is no such variable existing called "responseBody" (unless you're running inside postman which is not what the question was about)

Answer (score 0):

Postman return execution summary in Callback function. after execution if you save the summary in callback and return it. you can access request/response/ headers.

```js
function runcollection(callback){
   newman.run({
      collection: 'C:\\newman\\PMP Dependency latest collection\\Updated\\TestCollection.postman_collection.json',
      environment: 'C:\\newman\\PMP Dependency latest collection\\Updated\\Test.postman_environment.json',
      iterationCount :1
   },function(error, summary){
      callback(summary)
   });
}

runcollection(result => {console.log(result.run.executions[0].response.stream.toString())});
```